Request for cancellation of an approved interview
I have been invited for an interview for a postdoc position. Because of some private reasons I want to cancel the interview which was fixed for interview one day before interview. Is it common to cancel interview one day before?

Cancel or postpone? Cancelling  means you are not interested for the post you applied for.

Do you want to reschedule it, or are you not interested in the position?

I want to cancel it not postponing

Why does it matter if it's "normal"? What is your goal, what are you trying to achieve?

I have another offer and I have to finalize that today. The interview has been scheduled for tomorrow.

Most people are still interested just prior to an interview so late cancellation and leaving the process isn't "normal", or at least "common". But every case is different. You will do everyone a favor by just letting them know that you are no longer interested, thank you.
You don't need to give a reason, or you can say "personal reasons". Detail isn't required. But it is better to let them know so that the interviewers are freed up in their schedules.
I hope everything works out for you.
In the alternate case in which someone is still interested but something makes the interview impossible to attend, just apologize for the inconvenience and request a future interview. Again, detail on the reason isn't required, but a timely message will help several people including yourself.

Thank you very much @Buffy.
